# how to convert .lm file(language model) to .lm.bin(binary file)?

Tags: nlp

I am using pocketsphinx for offline speech recognition. I use lmtool to get language model and dictionary.But the language model has extension .lm but pocketsphinx requires .lm.bin file. So, how can I convert this?

Comment: Please show us what did you do so far.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to:
1. Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8-win32.zip

2. Unpackage sphinxbase-0.8-win32.zip. The folder will be PATH\
   In my case thats C:\Users\carope9\Desktop\
3. Move lm file to PATH\sphinxbase-0.8-win32\bin\Release
4. Open CMD and write cd PATH\sphinxbase-0.8-win32\bin\Release
5. Write sphinx_lm_convert -i YOUR_LM_FILE -o YOUR_LM.BIN_FILE
   example: sphinx_lm_convert -i es_ES.lm -o es_ES.lm.bin
6. Your new lm.bin file will be into PATH\sphinxbase-0.8-win32\bin\Release

If you don't use Windows need to download source files from http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz but I don't know how to install it I'm reading https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/c67930c0/?limit=25

P/D: According to some people this doesn't work, it worked for me and I don't know how to correct their error. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It worked for me but using the latest version of sphinxbase (sphinxbase-5prealpha-win32.zip) from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/5prealpha/ . It's important that it is the win32.zip file. With the 0.8 version I had the errors "Trigrams not in bigram order" and "Wrong magic header size number". The command I run is PATH\sphinxbase-5prealpha\win32\sphinxbase\bin\Release\Win32>sphinx_lm_convert -i en-70k-0.2.lm -o en-70k-0.2.lm.bin